# How plot the transformation of a region in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: functions, complex-numbers

I have the transformation $f(z)=e^{i 2\pi z}$, and i need show how is the plot of the region $S=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{C}: 0\leq x \leq 2 \land 1 \leq y \leq 2 \}$ under the transformation.

But i really don't know how to start, i've the component functions of $f(z)$ but i don't know what do with that. I appreciate your help. thanks.

Comment: Your region is a rectangle. Start with looking at where the edges are sent, and do that by first looking at where the corners are sent.

Comment: Doesn't directly address your question, but you may enjoy this interactive [web program](http://mathcs.holycross.edu/~ahwang/teach/software/Mappings/index.html) for showing images of disks or grids under a selection of complex polynomial mappings. (To play, move your cursor over the left-hand grid.)